# How do I correctly pass a variable to invoke-sqlcmd -serverinstance parameter? AmbiguousMatchException

Tags: powershell

```
Import-Module sqlps  
@serverObjects = @()  
cd "some location"   #This location contains a list of serverName\instance  
$serverObjects += ls  
cd "another location" #This location contains another list of serverName\instance  
$serverObjects += ls
```

At this point `$serverObjects.Name` returns a list of all `serverName\instance`
Example run of: `$serverObjects`

```
server1\instanceA  
server2\instanceB
```

Now I want to run some SQL against each of the `serverName\instance` saved in `$serverObjects`

```
foreach ($server in $serverObjects)  
{  
invoke-sqlcmd -inputfile "Direct path to file.sql" -serverinstance $server.Name   
}
```

This returns with the following errors:

```
 invoke-sqlcmd : Ambiguous match found.
At line:4 char:5  
+     invoke-sqlcmd -inputfile "Direct path to file.sql" -serverinstance ($s ...  
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (serverName\instance:PSObject) [Invoke-Sqlcmd],AmbiguousMatchException  
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionFailed,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
```

How can I pass my servernames\instances as a variable to the -serverinstance parameter and not run into the ambiguous match found error?

Comment: You could try `-serverinstance "$($server.Name)"` to make sure that it's actually treating the Name property as a string, and not something else

Comment: Still get the ambiguous match exception.

Comment: does the exact same command work if you give it the instance manually? if yes then closely inspect $server.Name and look for differences

Comment: Yes it works when given an instance manually, ex. -serverinstance "serverName\Instance".  

I don't see any differences between them... $server.Name gives the same value, along with $server.Name.toString()

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that perplexed me.  I thought it was because the calling function I wrote used the same parameter name as -ServerInstance (for consistency).

```
# build function to get permission scripts and save them to log table
function Get-PermProjectSQLUserPermissionScripts {

param (
     [parameter(Mandatory)][string[]]$Principal
    ,[string[]]$ServerInstance
)...
```

This inside the function later... I call:

`Invoke-SQLCmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Query $Query`

This returned:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : Value cannot be null.
> Parameter name: ServerInstance

But, if I called:

`Invoke-SQLCmd -ServerInstance $LiterallyAnyVariableNameExistingOrNot -Query $Query`

My function would successfully execute Invoke-SQLCmd despite $LiterallyAnyVariableNameExistingOrNot being undefined.

I followed Matthias' suggestion and changed my call to:

`Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $($ServerInstance) -Query $Query`

This worked, though I'm a bit confused why I had this problem in the first place.  I often "reuse" parameter names between functions to keep things consistent.

Answer (score -1):

I am getting the same as well where I cant pass a variable to the -ServerInstance parameter however when I write host the output, its definitely correct and its a string type variable.